# Navigation by specific inputted text in text box?

Tags: html

first post.  I am attempting to create a text "input" box that will allow any of three commands "who", "why" and "how" to link to corresponding pages in my website.  To clarify, I want my homepage to have a text box that will allow the user to type one of the three above commands then press "enter" to link to the corresponding page.  Sounds easy, but I am a super beginner.  Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would add a keydown listener to the input box in JavaScript and listen for keycode 13 (enter button keycode). If it is pressed, test the value for who, why, and how.

```
<input type="text" id="LinkBox" />

document.getElementById("LinkBox").onkeydown = function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    // 13 is keycode for the enter key
    if ( keyCode === 13 ) {
        if ( this.value === "who" ) {
            window.location = // who URL here
        } else if ( this.value === "why" ) {
            window.location = // why URL here
        } else if ( this.value === "how" ) {
            window.location = // how URL here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this site is incredible.  Good Karma your way.